# Setting font-size for dropdown in chrome does not seem to affect the styling

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome

I set the font-size for the dropdown in chrome, but it does not appear to change the size of the `<select>`

It works on FF - when i set the font-size as 15px, it is distinctively bigger

Comment: @sandeep: I find it ironic that I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Isn't this, technically speaking, the correct behaviour? If I change the `font-size` I don't want the element itself to change in size. I think it depends on wether the select element is by default inline or inline-block. Block elements don't change size according to font-size and inline elements do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some browsers will allow you to modify the `font-size` on its own and some will not.

You can *hack* the browser-specific style of a `select` element by setting a `border` style.

```css
select {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<select>
    <option>Quick</option>
    <option>Brown</option>
    <option>Fox</option>
</select>
```

Comment: >it actually does not change for me. this is very weird.

Answer (score 7):

If Chrome and Safari just ignore your **height**, **font-family** and **font-size** CSS settings for select:
Adding a border attribute could help Webkits to respect your settings.

Example:

```
select {
 border: 1px solid #a4a4a4; /*Same grey as default appearance*/
 ( background: transparent; /*Would work too, but adds an ugly black border*/ )
 font-family: times; /*Now in webkit too*/
 font-size: 30px; /*Now in webkit too*/
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another workaround is to style the `<select>` element with `-webkit-appearance: menulist-button;`.

```css
select { -webkit-appearance: menulist-button; font-size: 25px; }
```

```html
<select>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>BB</option>
    <option>CCC</option>
</select>
```